# Export excel file using PHPExcel

Tags: javascript, export, phpexcel

I am working on a application and trying to export Excel file using PHPExcel, data was manipulated/generated by some javascript methods so it's not on server.I have methods to export CSV and PDF files but i am trying to get that data in Excel file in some custom format.
 Here is gist of few files:  https://gist.github.com/gupta2205/959be9a10dbe1857609f

I am curious what can i write in here

```
   public function export($Sets, $disp_filter)
     {
    $excel_out  = new PHPExcel();
    $excel_out->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    var_dump($excel_out);

    $csv_out = $this->outputHumanReadableFilter($disp_filter);
    $csv_out []= array();

    $csv_out = array_merge($csv_out, $this->outputSampleDetails($Sets));
    $csv_out []= array();

    $csv_out = array_merge($csv_out, $this->outputQuestions($Sets));

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    ob_start();
    $rowCount = 1;
    foreach ($csv_out as $line)
    {
        $colCount = 'A';
        $col_values = explode(',', $line);
        foreach($col_values as $col_value){
            $excel_out->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colCount.$rowCount, $col_value);
            $colCount++;
        }
        $rowCount++;
    }

    return $excel_out;

}
```

How can i get the data in excel sheet ?
Sorry it might be lil silly question but i'm new to PHP and PHPExcel.

Comment: Give me the initial idea how can i start with getting data into cells

Comment: Have you looked at any of the examples provided, or read any of the documentation, which show how to store data in cells

Comment: Methods like `setCellValue()` and `fromArray()` might be particularly useful